# I am having issue with my splash screen as am not getting into the next activity

Tags: android, splash-screen

This is an example of splash screen but facing difficulty with it as I couldn't view my MainActivity class, couldn't be able to recognize the issue.Tried in manifest file by changing the action and the category name as well but could not be able to resolve to it.

Basically changed my `Intent intent  = new Intent();` as well but still the same goes on.

```
    public class SplashActivity extends Activity
    {

        MediaPlayer player;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);

            player = MediaPlayer.create(SplashActivity.this, R.raw.splash);
            player.start();
            Thread timer = new Thread() 
            {

                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    try
                    {               
                        sleep(4000);

                    }catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                        finish();
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setClass(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        stop();




                }
            };
            timer.start();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() 
        {
            super.onPause();
            player.release();
            finish();
        }


    }
```

> ====>And here is my manifest file --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mainsplashcreen"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/android_splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you have to show video or what in splash screen??

Comment: Remove `stop();` and it will work

Answer (score 1):

I would guess, that your problem is, that you finish your activity before you start the new one. If you call `finish()` on your activity, it will be destroyed, and so the `startActivity()` won't be called anymore (or if it will be called, it won't get a valid context anymore). So try to move the finish() method, at the end of your `run` method, that should solve the problem.

Comment: This is not true and not the problem. `startActivity()` will be called (in this case). The problem is stopping the `Thread` with `stop()`

Answer (score 0):

Another Very **Short,Simple and Effective** way of Implementing Flash Screen is as below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Handler handler=new Handler();
        Runnable gotoMain=new Runnable() {
        public void run() 
        {
          startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
          finish();
        }
      };
      handler.postDelayed(gotoMain, 4000);
    }
```

You just Replace you OnCreate Method with this one.

Comment: No the problem is still there java runtime exception it shows, as i said tried many things and by the way the stop() method is deprecated in Android 4.0 and if you notice then would have easily figured that am using gingerbread that is Android 2.3.3, anyways please anyone could help me in getting out of this. This is really becoming disaster.

Comment: Hey..have you tried the above solution??...i have used this code in my 2.1 Version

Comment: Just remove your whole onCreate and onPause()  method and replace the code with that of mine

Comment: No Haresh seriously its not working, am facing this simple issue for more than three hours.

Comment: Can you please put down the whole activity code..I would like to know that are you using TabHost or like things to display your Activity or a single standalone activity.

Comment: What this class is doing there MediaPlayer player; ??

Comment: I am using Media player bcos of a splash sound.Anyways My problem has been solved,Problem was not on the splash class it wasthe MainActivity class.I'd lyk to thank you and Param for helping me out..THANK YOU AGAIN...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things which you should take care of:
1. The usage of stop() and the place it is being used are not encouraged. Besides being deprecated,  it will also give you UnsupportedOperationExcecption.
2. Is your MediaPlayer being initialized correctly without any errors? Check the logs.
3. What is the reason you are using finish() in onPause() method? It is not recommended.
4. You are assigning MAIN action to both your activities. While it is allowed, it should be for a specific reason.

However, all these things should not avoid your application to go to the main activity. There may be the reasons with your main activity code.

Comment: I have omitted stop() method and also the finish() mthod from pause, It is showing java.lang.RuntimeException : Unable to start activity Components Info{com.mainsplashcreen.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Then it is simple, check on which line the Null Pointer exception exception is coming. Possibly in your Main Activity onCreate() you are trying to reference a null object.

Comment: Hey thanks finally i got to resolve.Thank you so very much Haresh Sir.

Comment: Yes Param actually i didn't define my button there...Thank you param sir.

Comment: Good to hear, then mark any answer as resolved to close this question.